# Getting SessionScoped bean from HttpSessionListener?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, httpsession, servlet-listeners

Hey guys.  I'm trying to get a session bean in a HttpSessionListener so that when the user logs out or the session expires I can delete some files that the user created in the application.  I'm guessing the session bean doesn't exist because the session is destroyed.  I was hoping to still delete these files some how.  Thanks for the help.

```
   @WebListener
    public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

        @Override
        public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
            HttpSession session = se.getSession();
            System.out.print(getTime() + " (session) Created:");
            System.out.println("ID=" + session.getId() + " MaxInactiveInterval="
                    + session.getMaxInactiveInterval());
        }

        @Override
        public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
            HttpSession session = se.getSession();

            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            //UserSessionBean userSessionBean = (UserSessionBean) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{userSessionBean}", UserSessionBean.class)
            UserSessionBean userSessionBean = (UserSessionBean) session.getAttribute("userSessionBean");

            System.out.println(session.getId());
            System.out.println("File size :" + userSessionBean.getFileList().size());

            for (File file : userSessionBean.getFileList()) {
                file.delete();
            }
        } 
    }
```

To BalusC:  I'm back to the method you previously had in mind.  Streaming the bytes to the user wasn't flexible in my application.  I found that I needed to do a lot of things in ajax on the page that was not possible if I had to send a non ajax request to stream a file to be downloaded.  This way the heavy lifting is done with an ajax call(generating the document) and the fast and easy work is can be done with a non ajax call.

```
   @ManagedBean(name = "userSessionBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserSessionBean implements Serializable, HttpSessionBindingListener {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserSessionBean.class);
    @Inject
    private User currentUser;
    @EJB
    UserService userService;
    private List<File> fileList;

    public UserSessionBean() {

        fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void onLoad() {

        Principal principal = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();
        String email = principal.getName();

        if (email != null) {
            currentUser = userService.findUserbyEmail(email);
        } else {

            logger.error("Couldn't find user information from login!");
        }
    }

    public User getCurrentUser() {
        return currentUser;
    }

    public void setCurrentUser(User currentUser) {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
    }

    public List<File> getFileList() {
        return fileList;
    }

    @Override
    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {

        logger.info("UserSession unbound");
        logger.info(String.valueOf(fileList.size()));
        for (File file : fileList) {
            logger.info(file.getName());
            file.delete();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        logger.info("UserSessionBean bound");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work fine. Note that the `FacesContext` isn't necessarily available there since there's not necessarily means of a HTTP request in the thread running at that point, but you already outcommented that. Are you sure that you was *actually* running the code as shown in the question? Clean, rebuild, redeploy, etc.

An alternative is to let your `UserSessionBean` implement [`HttpSessionBindingListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html) and then do the job in the [`valueUnbound()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html#valueUnbound%28javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingEvent%29) method.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserSessionBean implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

    @Override
    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        for (File file : files) {
            file.delete();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hey BalusC I tried this too.  I know that the file list has file objects in it.  I can test that by logging the size in my application.  However when unbound is called the file object size is 0.  That's the same problem I have with the session listener.  I've updated my original post with the code.  I'm 100% sure that the list is getting objects.

Comment: Not that I know of.  The list is part of the userSessionBean object.  I can retrieve and add to the list fine within the application.