# SessionListener and Application Context conflict

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, el, managed-bean

This is my session handler class:

```
public class Sessionlistener implements HttpSessionListener {

  @ManagedProperty(value="#{sessionCount}")
  private SessionInfo info;

  @Override
  public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {  
    info.setActive(info.getActive() + 1);
  }

  @Override
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
    info.setActive(info.getActive() - 1);
  }

}
```

.. and this is my sessionCount bean:

```
@ApplicationScoped 
@ManagedBean(name="sessionCount",eager=true) 
public class SessionInfo {
  private int active = 0;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    System.out.println("sessionCount object created");
  }

  public void setActive(int active) {
    this.active = active;
  }

  public int getActive() {
    return active;
  }
}
```

The error is:
When `SessionListener` initializes it's `@ManagedProperty`, `null` is injected because `sessionCount` is not created yet. How can I solve this? On the other hand if I put `sessionCount` field in `SessionListener` class and make `SessionListener` class an `@ApplicationScoped` bean, I cant access it via `#{applicationContext.listenerBean.active}`.

The actual question here is: if a class is `HttpSessionlistener` instance we cant use it as an application context object? Is it true

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239103/getting-sessionscoped-bean-from-httpsessionlistener

Comment: You cant inject values as ManagedProperty in HttpSessionListener.

Comment: so now I know filters and listener can not inject values  is there another exceptions?